# MyBatis-Spring: SqlSessionFactoryBean initialization: connection timeout

Tags: spring, configuration, mybatis, dtd, xml

I am migrating from iBatis 2 to MyBatis 3 in a Spring 3.0 environment.  When I attempt to deploy the application, or even just run a JUnit test, the config initialization fails with a connection timeout error as follows:

> Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [testContext-jndi.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error creating document instance.  Cause: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

It looks like a missing http proxy, but my eclipse proxy settings have always worked for all my other code.  My DTD definitions appear to be correct.

I am using Spring 3.0.0, and have included the following jars in my classpath:

- mybatis-3.2.2.jar
- mybatis-spring-1.2.0.jar

The relevant spring configuration is as follows:

fooContext-data.xml - (this is the test/resources configuration.  When deploying to a web container, the spring-configured data source uses a JNDI lookup to get credentials.  They both fail the same way.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans>

    <bean id="dataSourceFoo" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" >
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = (LOAD_BALANCE=on)(FAILOVER=on)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=foo1)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=foo2)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=foo.bar.boz)))"/>
        <property name="username" value="fooUser"/>
        <property name="password" value="fooPass"/>             
    </bean>

    <!-- MyBatis stuff -->
    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceFoo" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="sqlMapConfig.xml" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

sqlMapConfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
        PUBLIC "-//www.mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">

<configuration>

    <properties resource="ibatis.properties" />

    <mappers>
        <mapper resource="foo/dao/maps/mybatis/SqlMap1.xml"/>
        <mapper resource="foo/dao/maps/mybatis/SqlMap2.xml"/>
        <mapper resource="foo/dao/maps/mybatis/SqlMap3.xml"/>
        <mapper resource="foo/dao/maps/mybatis/SqlMap4.xml"/>
        <mapper resource="foo/dao/maps/mybatis/SqlMap5.xml"/>
        <mapper resource="foo/dao/maps/mybatis/SqlMap6.xml"/>
        <mapper resource="foo/dao/maps/mybatis/SqlMap7.xml"/>
        <mapper resource="foo/dao/maps/mybatis/SqlMap8.xml"/>
        <mapper resource="foo/dao/maps/mybatis/SqlMap9.xml"/>
        <mapper resource="foo/dao/maps/mybatis/SqlMap10.xml"/>
        <mapper resource="foo/dao/maps/mybatis/SqlMap11.xml"/>
        <mapper resource="foo/dao/maps/mybatis/SqlMap12.xml"/>
        <mapper resource="foo/dao/maps/mybatis/SqlMap13.xml"/>
        <mapper resource="foo/dao/maps/mybatis/SqlMap14.xml"/>
        <mapper resource="foo/dao/maps/mybatis/SqlMap15.xml"/>
    </mappers>

</configuration>
```

I noticed that some others were having this problem, and it was related to something being wrong with the DTD of the myBatis xml, or having a bad network connection, preventing them from pulling down the DTD definition.  I do not see how I could have this problem, as all these bases appear to be covered in my scenario.

I've been at this problem for a day and a half, having scourged the documentation for both MyBatis, and MyBatis-Spring, as well as a good bit of this site and others.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this problem on the myBatis users site here: 
[DTD verification when www.mybatis.org is down](http://mybatis-user.963551.n3.nabble.com/How-to-skip-DTD-verification-when-www-mybatis-org-is-down-td4026165.html)

Turns out that my DTD links were not supposed to have www in front of them.  That is, rather than:

```
    <!DOCTYPE configuration
        PUBLIC "-//www.mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
```

they were supposed to read:

```
    <!DOCTYPE configuration
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
```

I changed these, and now it works.